# SVG chart responsive from Illustrator

Tags: svg, charts, responsive-design, responsive, adobe-illustrator

I'm designing a chart in Illustrator and will export it in SVG. Is there some way to make it responsive so that the result acts as the following animation? i.e.: circles won't distort and lines will keep the stroke size after the screen reducing. If I have to edit the SVG generated by Illustrator, it's quite OK. Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dQxn.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on what you want to achieve. First of all a real chart should not be drawn in iIllustrator. That's why I imagine it's not a real chart. Just a fantasy image.

If what you need to achieve is something like the linked gif here you are: you can achieve this by using `preserveAspectRatio="none"` for your svg. Also the lines and paths must have `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;`

> *This value modifies the way an object is stroked. Normally stroking
>   involves calculating stroke outline of the shapeʼs path in current
>   user coordinate system and filling that outline with the stroke paint
>   (color or gradient). The resulting visual effect of this value is that
>   the stroke width is not dependant on the transformations of the
>   element (including non-uniform scaling and shear transformations) and
>   zoom level.*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect

As you can see instead of circles I'm using very short lines with `stroke-linecap: round;` This will make them looking like circles and since `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;` they will preserve the shape.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:100%; height:300px;}
path{fill:none;stroke-width:4px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;}
line{stroke-width:40px;stroke-linecap: round;vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M5,25L195,25M5,50L195,50M5,75L195,75" stroke="black" />
  <g stroke="red">
  <line x1="35" y1="25" x2="35.01" y2="25" />
  <line x1="155" y1="50" x2="155.01" y2="50" />
  <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="75.01" y2="75" />
  <path d="M35,25L155,50 75,75"/>
  </g>
  
  <g stroke="green">
  <line x1="95" y1="25" x2="95.01" y2="25" />
  <line x1="75" y1="50" x2="75.01" y2="50" />
  <line x1="155" y1="75" x2="155.01" y2="75" />
  <path d="M95,25L75,50 155,75"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot! What do you recommend to create charts in SVG?

Comment: In order to create a chart I would use javascript.